# max_connection does not exist in my.cnf

Tags: linux, centos, apache

I just installed apache 2.2.3 and already had the error "too many connections". I went to my.cnf to increase max_connections but its not there!

The only content in it is:

```
[mysqld] datadir=/var/lib/mysql socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock user=mysql
# Default to using old password format for compatibility with mysql 3.x
# clients (those using the mysqlclient10 compatibility package). old_passwords=1

# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks;
# to do so, uncomment this line:
# symbolic-links=0

[mysqld_safe] log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

So what can I do to increase max_connections?

Where can I find it?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Just add the line with `max_connections` yourself, and restart the server :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you see a "too many connections" error in **Apache**, then editing my.cnf will not help, because that belongs to **MySQL**.

Edit /etc/apache2/apache2.conf instead.

In a default install, you will probably have the traditional prefork mpm, so you will need to edit the MaxClients directive inside the <IfModule mpm_prefork_module> block. If you are not sure, you can edit MaxClients in the other mpm blocks too.

Restart the server after changing config (/etc/init.d/apache2 restart).

Comment: thatnsk alot damon! thats exactly it!